# How to ask RabbitMQ to retry when business Exception occurs in Spring Asynchronous MessageListener use case

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a Spring AMQP message listener running.

```
public class ConsumerService implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            testService.process(message); //This process method can throw Business Exception
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
           //Here we can just log the exception. How the retry attempt is made?
        } catch (Exception e) {
           //Here we can just log the exception.  How the retry attempt is made?
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there could be exception coming out during process. I want to retry because of a particular error in Catch block. I cannot through exception in onMessage. 
How to tell RabbitMQ to there is an exception and retry?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since `onMessage()` doesn't allow to throw checked exceptions you can wrap the exception in a `RuntimeException` and re-throw it.

```
try {
    testService.process(message);
} catch (BusinessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Note however that this may result in the message to be re-delivered indefinitely. Here is how this works:

RabbitMQ supports rejecting a message and asking the broker to requeue it. This is shown [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html). But RabbitMQ doesn't natively have a mechanism for retry policy, e.g. setting max retries, delay, etc.

When using Spring AMQP, "requeue on reject" is the default option. Spring's [`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) will by default do this when there is an unhandled exception. So in your case you just need to re-throw the caught exception. Note however that if you cannot process a message and you always throw the exception this will be re-delivered indefinitely and will result in an infinite loop.

You can override this behaviour per message by throwing a [`AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.4.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.html) exception, in which case the message will not be requeued.

You can also switch off the "requeue on reject" behavior of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` entirely by setting

```
container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false)
```

When a message is rejected and not requeued it will either be lost or transferred to a DLQ, if one is set in RabbitMQ.

If you need a retry policy with max attempts, delay, etc the easiest is to setup a spring "stateless" `RetryOperationsInterceptor` which will do all retries within the thread (using `Thread.sleep()`) without rejecting the message on each retry (so without going back to RabbitMQ for each retry). When retries are exhausted, by default a warning will be logged and the message will be consumed. If you want to send to a DLQ you will need either a [`RepublishMessageRecoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.3.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/retry/RepublishMessageRecoverer.html) or a custom [`MessageRecoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.3.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/retry/MessageRecoverer.html) that rejects the message without requeuing (in that latter case you should also [setup](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) a RabbitMQ DLQ on the queue). Example with default message recoverer:

```
container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {
        org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder
                .stateless()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2, 5000)
                .build()
});
```

This obviously has the drawback that you will occupy the Thread for the entire duration of the retries. You also have the option to use a "stateful" `RetryOperationsInterceptor`, which will send the message back to RabbitMQ for each retry, but the delay will still be implemented with `Thread.sleep()` within the application, plus setting up a stateful interceptor is a bit more complicated.

Therefore, if you want retries with delays without occupying a `Thread` you will need a much more involved custom solution using TTL on RabbitMQ queues. If you don't want exponential backoff (so delay doesn't increase on each retry) it's a bit simpler. To implement such a solution you basically create another queue on rabbitMQ with arguments: `"x-message-ttl": <delay time in milliseconds>` and `"x-dead-letter-exchange":"<name of the original queue>"`. Then on the main queue you set `"x-dead-letter-exchange":"<name of the queue with the TTL>"`. So now when you reject and don't requeue a message RabbitMQ will redirect it to the second queue. When TTL expires it will be redirected to the original queue and thus redelivered to the application. So now you need a retry interceptor that rejects the message to RabbitMQ after each failure and also keeps track of the retry count. To avoid the need to keep state in the application (because if your application is clustered you need to replicate state) you can calculate the retry count from the `x-death` header that RabbitMQ sets. See more info about this header [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html). So at that point implementing a custom interceptor is easier than customising the Spring stateful interceptor with this behaviour.

Also check [the section about retries in the Spring AMQP reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#async-listeners).

Comment: Thans Nazreet for your very detailed explanation. I have few more doubts.  It is clear that I have to throw a Runtime Exception to go for message retry.  Also use a RetryInterceptor which limits the retry attempts.  1. On what cases we would go with Stateful interceptor/Stateless Interceptor? 2. Also, with Retry option configured, wil the other messages left unattended till this all retry completes? It should be a separate thread to retry rt?  3. How about creating a separate queue for retry and custom retry implementation?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. To answer your questions: 1) Stateful/Stateless retry interceptors are generally used in Spring (batch, integration, amqp, etc) so they have various use cases. But in the AMQP message consumers case, I don't think stateful provides a very big benefit as I mentioned. The difference is that stateful will send the message back to RabbitMQ on each retry (but after sleeping, if backoff is configured).

Comment: 2) What will happen with the other messages depends on the number of concurrent consumers. Each consumer is a separate thread. You set this with container.setConcurrentConsumers(). 3) Custom retry implementation is quite involved to explain in a comment. I'll try to find time to explain later.

Comment: Another concern related to the stateful retry interceptor is that if you have a clustered application (multiple nodes with consumers on the same queue) you need to find a way to replicate the state across nodes. Otherwise you might get the double number of retries in the worst case.

Comment: Added a brief description of a backoff solution that doesn't involve Thread.sleep by using RabbitMQ TTL. If you need exponential backoff it gets even more involved. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful.

Comment: For implementing this what should be the ack mode manual ? or auto ?