# Spring AMQP (Rabbit) Listener goes in a loop in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

```
@Bean
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    template.setExchange(amqpProperties.getRabbitMqTopicExchangeName());
    return template;
}

@Bean
@Conditional (OperationsCondition.class)
 SimpleMessageListenerContainer opsMessageListenerContainer() {
    return listenerContainer(amqpProperties.getRabbitMqOperationsQueue(), 
            amqpProperties.getInitialRabbitOperationsConsumerCount(), 
            amqpProperties.getMaximumRabbitOperationsConsumerCount(),
            opsReceiver());
}

@Bean
@Conditional (OperationsCondition.class)
OperationsListener opsReceiver() {
    return new OperationsListener();
}

private SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(String queue,
        int initConsumers,int maxConsumers, MessageListener listener)
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(queue);
    container.setMessageListener(listener);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(initConsumers);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumers);
    container.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return container;
}
```

Message listener is:

```
public class OperationsListener  implements MessageListener
{
    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getInstance(OperationsListener.class);

    @Autowired (required=true)
    private OperationsProcessor processor;
    @Autowired (required=true)
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();        
        converter.setJsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        OperationsMessage request = (OperationsMessage)converter.fromMessage(message);
        processor.createMessage(request);
        //This is throwing a JPA database exception
        processor.createOperation(request);
    }
}
```

processor.createOperation() is throwing an exception due to database issue. Problem is that message listener is going in a loop and message keeps coming back.

My processor class:

```
@Component
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) 
public class OperationsProcessor
{
...............

    public void createOperation(OperationsMessage message)
    {
            try
            {
                .............
                .............
                //this call throws exception.
                opsRepo.create(operation,null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.error(e);
            }

    }
}
```

opsRepo.create throws an exception. Even though i am catching error, i was hoping that message doesn't gets sent again by spring amqp. Not sure why same message keeps coming back.

EDIT:

I think i found some pointers on how to deal with this. The cause is that spring is requeing events upon failure and this is the default nature. 
Found an helpful thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979840/how-to-ask-rabbitmq-to-retry-when-business-exception-occurs-in-spring-asynchrono) and [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/117495-exception-causes-infinite-loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To confirm what you have found, this is [clearly documented in the reference manual section "Exception Handling"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#exception-handling).

Comment: True. I thought i read entire document few months back. I guess i missed important sections. Thank you for the link. I am throwing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException in case of any exceptions in the listener. This way error is logged as well as message is not retried. Works for now.